# Can't find linked class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two projects in the same solution and I have linked a class DatabaseFunctions.cs to the second one.

[image]

The problem is that when I reference it in the GUI_Teacher.cs I get the error:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DatabaseFunctions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Teachers application    C:\Users\user1\source\repos\IASLSN\Teachers application\GUI_Teacher.cs

Comment: The teacher code you are missing a "using" statement at top of module.

Comment: what should I have next to using?

Comment: The namespace.class of where the code is located in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, you are simply missing a reference.

Take the following steps to add a reference

1. Right click on the `GUI_Teacher.cs` project and click on Add Reference
2. From the left side of the Add Reference dialog, click on Solution
3. Select `DatabaseFunctions.cs` from the list and click OK to close the dialog.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? I tried your steps in VS 2017 Community and cannot follow your solution. After a right click on the project `Teachers application` I can choose `Add`, then `Reference`. In the `Reference Manager` dialog, I can add other projects (the .csproj file) to this project. But I am not able to add another C# source file (.cs files). Am I missing something?

Comment: @GWimpassinger do you want to create a new cs file or add an existing one to your project?

Comment: Neither? I want to understand your answer for this question/problem. If I reconstruct the problem, with the information jakev has given, I am not able to apply your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the source file `DatabaseFunctions.cs` you have something like

```
using System;

namespace SomeNamespaceName 
{
    public class DatabaseFunctions
    {
    }
}
```

To use the class in your `GUI_Teacher.cs` source file you need to add either `using SomeNamespaceName;` at the top or use the fully qualified type name `SomeNamespaceName.DatabaseFunctions` instead.

Keep in mind that the name of a sourcecode file like your `DatabaseFunctions.cs` for example has no connection to the name of a class or a namespace in that file. You can put a class like `public class DatabaseFunctions { }` in a file called `foo.cs`. And in the `using` directive at the top of your sourcefiles you provide a namespace and not a filename.